# Set only a single input (type=radio ) to "required" within php foreach loop

Tags: php, html, foreach, requiredfieldvalidator

I am stuck with the following problem:

I dynamically create Inputs of type radio within a php foreach loop. However, I want only the first input that is created to have the "required" property.

My Code is similar to this:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $value) 
{
?>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="option" class="option" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $value['text']; ?>
            </p>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php                                                                                               }
?>
```

Any way I can solve this? Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can do like it:

```
<?php 
$num = 0;
foreach ($data as $value) {
$num++;
?>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="option" class="option" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($num == 1) ? 'required' : ''; ?>>
                    <?php echo $value['text']; ?>
            </p>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```